# What is the best way to automatically create a movie from my iPhoto videos?

Tags: photos.app, imovie

When I first started using a Mac almost 6 years ago iMovie had a mode (automovie?) where I could just throw a folder at it and it would create a movie from all the photos and videos. This was a great way for someone with no time to create a family video.

Now I'm trying to do basically the same thing with iMovie '09 and iPhoto and can't figure out the best way.

I want an all-Apple or free solution to just taking all the videos from my iPhoto library and putting them into a movie in chronological order. I really won't want to spend hours dragging and dropping clips into a movie (either on my Mac or on the iPad in iMovie or Avid Studio).

What is the best way to do this?

EDIT: I realized I have iMovie '09 not '11 as first reported so that might change the technique. In the bottom left of iMovie I do see an entry labeled iPhoto Videos but it is always empty.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the **iPhoto Library**.

   [image]
2. Click **Create** → **Movie** and select **No Theme**.
3. Select the photos/videos.
4. Press **E**.

   All the photos and videos will be added sequentially to the timeline.
5. Export your timeline normally.

Comment: All this is from within iMovie?

Comment: @davidethell Indeed it is

Comment: Ok, finally getting around to trying this. It isn't working. I have iPhoto 9.5.1 and iMovie '09 (8.0.6). I don't see the iPhoto Library option you mention so I assume that's something specific to iMovie '11. Any idea how to make it work in '09?

Comment: I have iMovie 10 (not '10), and hitting "E" just makes it beep.